# Google calendar api, redirect uri mismatch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, google-calendar-api

i was trying to integrate google calendar api for my ruby application, in google developer console i gave my redirect uri

`http://localhost:3000`

`http://localhost:3000/auth/google_oauth2/callback`

```
400. That’s an error.
```

Error: redirect_uri_mismatch

```
redirect_uri=http://localhost:9292/
```

it keep getting port 9292 even though i mention 3000

i have followed these link 
 [ruby quickstart from google](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/ruby)

Comment: can you post your intializer file where you specified the `customer_key` and `customer_secret` for google developer console

Comment: {"web":{"client_id":"myclientid","auth_uri":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth","token_uri":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token","auth_provider_x509_cert_url":"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs","client_secret":"myclientsecret","redirect_uris":["http://localhost:3000","https://localhost:3000"],"javascript_origins":["http://localhost:3000","https://localhost:3000"]}}

Comment: @priya : Can you try by run your server on port 9292 by `rails s -p 9292` and change in google console accordingly and check that works for you or not? I guess there is `DNS` or `NAT` issue

Comment: in Google developer console add http:/ /localhost  remove the port.

Comment: @DaImTo tried still redirect uri issue using port 9292 again

Comment: @GaganGami tried it before it wont workout

Comment: Then add http:// localhost:9292/  The redirect uri on google developers console must match the URI you are sending it from.

Answer (score 0):

I ran in the same problem and unfortunately wasted my 4 hours on that silly problem , as i see that you're using `gem "omniauth-google-oauth2"` actually there is no scope defined , you need to add scope otherwise it will keep misleading you . I used keys in intializer like below
`Provider :google_oauth2, 'customer_key', 'my_sec' , {:scope => 'email,profile' }`

and update your `gem file` like below

`gem 'omniauth-oauth2', '~> 1.3.1'`

`gem "omniauth-google-oauth2"`

**Update**

`origin Url -> http://localhost:3000`

`callback Url-> http://localhost:3000/auth/google_oauth2/callback`

`routes.rb ->  get "auth/:provider/callback", to: 'registration#create_session'`

Comment: can you please mention your redirect uri which you gave in google developer console

Comment: where should i mention this                Provider :google_oauth2, 'customer_key', 'my_sec' , {:scope => 'email,profile' }

Comment: in your `config/initializer/omniauth.rb` . You have to create `omniauth.rb` if not yet created

Comment: @priya did you figured it out ? I also updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

Just an addition to @ImranNaqvi's answer; when I ran 'bundle install' after changing the version of omniauth-oauth2, the terminal complained that my omniauth-oauth2 is locked at version 1.4.0. If this happens, you will need to go into the gem.lock file (not gem list) and change the omniauth-oauth2 version to 1.3.1. Then 'bundle install'.